# JavaScript, Ajax request on click, does not work, no errors, unable to get uid

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

Can someone help me to understand what is about my javascript that it's not working. It should be giving me uid at the click on link but I get nothing so far. It should show or do something at link but it doesn't do anything nor any error in the console log either. I'll really appreciate some help.

JS.file

```
let pn_uid = function(){

let _has_loaded_uid = false
let _cached_uid = null

function pn_uid (cb) {

    let uid = (tp && tp.pianoId && tp.pianoId.getUser()) ? (tp.pianoId.getUser()).uid : null
    if (uid == null) return cb(null)

    tp.push(["init", function() {
        var params = {
            rid : window.pn_bookmark.rid
        };
        var callback = function(response) {
            _has_loaded_uid = true
            if (response.access && response.access.granted) {
         
                _cached_uid = uid
                return cb(uid)
            }
            else {
                _cached_uid = null
                return cb(null)
            }
        }
        tp.api.callApi("/access/check", params, callback);
    }]);
}

return {
    check: pn_uid
}

 let pn_bookmark = function(){
function pn_bookmark_load() {
    pn_uid.check((uid) => {
        const data = {
            'action': 'pn_bookmark_get',
            '_ajax_nonce': window.pn_bookmark.sec,
            'uid': uid
        };
        jQuery.post(window.pn_bookmark.ajax_url, data, function(response) {
        let element = document.querySelector("#pn-com-container-bookmark a");
        console.log(response.bookmarkslist);
        console.log(response.data);
        element.innerHTML = response.bookmarkhtml;
        });
    });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    pn_bookmark_load();
});
}()
```

Controller.php

```
       function getBookmarks($user_id) {
    global $wpdb;

    $query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT postid FROM bookmarks WHERE user_id='%s' ORDER BY date_created", $user_id);
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A);

     $response = [];
    foreach ( $results as $result ) {
    $response[] = new UserData($result);       
    }

    var_dump($results);
    return $response;
  }
```

file.php

```
 <?php

  class Bookmarking {

/**
* @var UserController
*/
private $userModel;

/**
* @var CommentController
*/
private $bookmarkingModel;

public function __construct($bookmarkingModel, $userModel) {
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_pn_bookmark_get', array( $this, 'pn_bookmark_get' ) ); 
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_pn_bookmark_get', array( $this, 'pn_bookmark_get' ) );
    add_shortcode( 'display_saved_bookmarks', array($this, 'get_all_bookmarks_shortcode'));

    $this->userModel = $userModel;
    $this->bookmarkingModel = $bookmarkingModel;
}

     private function bookmarkJS() {
     $nonce = wp_create_nonce('pn_bookmark_get_nonce');
    if (class_exists("PianoSettings")) {
        $settings = new \PianoSettings();
        $rid = $settings->getResource();
    } else {
        $rid = "";
    }
    wp_enqueue_script('pn_bookmarks',
        plugins_url("../../www/js/pn_bookmarks.js", __FILE__)
    );
    wp_localize_script( 
        'pn_bookmarks',
        'pn_bookmarks',
        array(
            'pn_bookmarks' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
            'sec' => $nonce,
            'rid' => $rid ) );
}


    public function pn_bookmark_get() {
    check_ajax_referer( 'pn_bookmark_get_nonce', 'nonce' );
   
    if (isset($_POST['uid'])) {
        $piano_user_id = $_POST['uid']; 

        $data = [
            'piano_user_id' => $piano_user_id
        ];
        
       $bookmarkslist = $this->$bookmarkingModel->getBookmarksList($piano_user_id);
       $bookmarkhtml = $this->get_all_bookmarks_shortcode();

        wp_send_json(["s" => true, "data" => $data, "bookmarkslist" => $bookmarkslist, "bookmarkhtml" => $bookmarkhtml]);
    }
}

 public function get_all_bookmarks_shortcode() {

    $this->bookmarkJS();

    $bookmarkhtml = <<<HTML
    <div id="pn-com-container-bookmark">
    <a href="#">View Bookmarks</a>
    </div>
    HTML;

    return $bookmarkhtml;

   }

 }
```

Comment: does the ajax request get sent OK? ( do you see the request in the dev tools/ network tab? )

Comment: The above code has an unbalanced number of curly braces... 14open/13close

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I get absolutely no errors or any indication that it shows it isn't working or it's working which is more confusing. 

I can see that rid and sec - getting posted through page source but no indication of uid, I think the request does not get send at all.

Also, I tried to clean the code which might have caused the unbalanced brackets.

Comment: Please consider using a linter? The code posted has syntax errors (JavaScript specifically)